# check if user is in active directory group before adding to group

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

```vb
   Private Sub AddUserToGroup1(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal GroupName As String)
        Using ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
            ' find your user
            Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, UserName)
            If user IsNot Nothing Then
                ' find the group in question
                Dim group As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, GroupName)
                ' if found....
                If group IsNot Nothing Then
                    ' add user to group
                    group.Members.Add(user)
                    group.Save()

                End If
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

the list of groups to which you want to add the user is in the Listbox

```vb
  For Each lb As String In LB1.Items
            AddUserToGroup("TestUser", lb)
        Next
```

The code is fully working, but if the user is already a member of one of the groups, then an error occurs that the Object already exists

Tell me how to check that if the user already exists in the group, then do not add it again, and if it does not exist in the group, then add it?

I also found a function that checks if there is a user in the group (returns True/False).
But I can't figure out how to combine these 2 codes. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

```vb
Public Function IsUserInGroup(ByVal userName As String, ByVal groupName As String) As Boolean
        Using context = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
            Using searcher = New PrincipalSearcher(New UserPrincipal(context) With {.SamAccountName = userName})
                Using user = TryCast(searcher.FindOne(), UserPrincipal)
                    Return user IsNot Nothing AndAlso user.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupName)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcollection.contains) before you use `Add()`:

```
If Not group.Members.Contains(user) Then
    group.Members.Add(user)
    group.Save()
End If
```